# Excel like web page

Tags: php, jquery, html, excel, twitter-bootstrap

Here I am trying to make a Excel like web page in which all kinds of filters can be applied.  Data is fetched using php array.  I almost succeeded in creating that page.  But performance-wise I am lacking.  I have [read](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) this but it does not seem to help.  I have 5000 cells which is currently taking around 13-15 sec.

Plugins used are:

[DataTable](http://datatables.net/)

[Multi Select Chekbox](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

Below is my Web page code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html id="top">

    <head>
    <?php
   $_SESSION['LEAGUE']="dashbordHighlight";
     $_SESSION['DASHBOARD']="";
            include_once('database/Insert.php');
            include_once('database/Select.php');
            $getleauge = new Select;    
    $selectTargetLeaugeTable = array();     
            $selectTargetLeaugeTable =$getleauge->selectTargetLeaugeTable();
            //print_r($selectTargetLeaugeTable);
    function uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($arr,$str){

        $temp = array();
        for($x=0;$x<count($arr);$x++){

        $temp[$x] = $arr[$x][$str];

        }

    //print_r(array_unique($temp));
    return array_unique($temp);

    }
        $_SESSION['selectTargetLeaugeTable'] = $selectTargetLeaugeTable;
        $getAlpha = new Select;
        $distinctvalues_an = uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Account Name"); sort($distinctvalues_an);
        $parent_name= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Parent Name");sort($parent_name);
        $Score_in_senario1= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Score");sort($Score_in_senario1);
        $Latest_Rank= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Latest Rank");sort($Latest_Rank);
        $Previous_Rank= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Previous Rank");sort($Previous_Rank);
        $Ranking_Trend_voltility= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Ranking Trend voltility");sort($Ranking_Trend_voltility);
        $Ranking_Movement_Justification= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Ranking Movement Justification");sort($Ranking_Movement_Justification);
        $hq= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"hq");sort($hq);
        $account_status= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Account Status");sort($account_status);
        $account_industry= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Account Industry");sort($account_industry);

        $cg_sector= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"CG Sector");sort($cg_sector);
        $Incumbent_SBU= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Incumbent SBU");sort($Incumbent_SBU);
        $revenue_annual= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Revenue Annual");sort($revenue_annual);
        $it_budget= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"IT Budget");sort($it_budget);
        $alleviate_test_status= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Alleviate test status");sort($alleviate_test_status);
        $BDE= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"BDE");sort($BDE);
        $BDE_Last_Meeting_with_Account= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"BDE Last Meeting with Account");sort($BDE_Last_Meeting_with_Account);
        $BDE_Account_Interaction_Comments= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"BDE Account Interaction Comments");sort($BDE_Account_Interaction_Comments);
        $Campaign_Ran= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Campaign");sort($Campaign_Ran);
        $Campaign_Date= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Campaign Date");sort($Campaign_Date);
        $Campaign_Outcome_Details= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Campaign Outcome Details");sort($Campaign_Outcome_Details);
        $Last_Update= uniqueMultiDimentionalArray($selectTargetLeaugeTable,"Last Update");sort($Last_Update);

    ?>
    <style>
    #preloader  {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         background-color: #fefefe;
         z-index: 9999999;
        height: 100%;
     }

    #status  {
         width: 15%;
         height: 300px;
         position: absolute;
         left: 43%;
         top: 4%;
         background-image: url(images/ajax-loader.gif);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center;
        text-align:center;
     }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php include 'externalLinks.php'; ?>
    <!-- /Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <style>

    td.highlight {
        background-color: whitesmoke !important;
    }
    .jafa,.input-group-addon,.input-group-btn{display:none !important;}
    .btn-group ul.dropdown-menu{position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:999999999;}

    </style>

    <title>OppInsights</title>
    </head>
    <!--CSS styles-->
    <div id="preloader">
      <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    <body style="background:url(images/BG/NewDesignBG/bgTexture.jpg) repeat;">
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <div style="margin:66px auto 50px;padding:0px;">
<div class="row newTable" style="margin:11px auto 50px;padding:10px;">
          <table id="newTable" class="cell-border order-column display hover row-border" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-order="[[ 0, &quot;asc&quot; ]]">
      <thead>
      <tr style="background:#bf6819;color:#FFF;font-size:12px;">
            <th class="one" >

            <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable form-control"  multiple="multiple" name="account_name[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($distinctvalues_an);$q ++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $distinctvalues_an[$q] ?>"  selected > <?php echo $distinctvalues_an[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

            </th>
            <th class="two" >

            <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="parent_name[]">
         <?php 
        for($q=0;$q<count($parent_name);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $parent_name[$q] ?>"  selected > <?php echo $parent_name[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>   </div>  </div>

            </th>
            <th class="three" >

                <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Score_in_senario1[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Score_in_senario1);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo number_format($Score_in_senario1[$q],2); ?>"  selected> <?php echo number_format($Score_in_senario1[$q],2); ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>


            </th>
           <th class="four" >


                <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Latest_Rank[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Latest_Rank);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Latest_Rank[$q]?>" selected > <?php echo $Latest_Rank[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select> 



          </th>
          <th class="five" >


                    <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Previous_Rank[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Previous_Rank);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Previous_Rank[$q] ?>"  selected > <?php echo $Previous_Rank[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>




          </th>
          <th class="six" >

                    <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Ranking_Trend_voltility[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Ranking_Trend_voltility);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Ranking_Trend_voltility[$q]?>"  selected > <?php echo $Ranking_Trend_voltility[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>




          </th>
          <th class="seven" >


          <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Ranking_Movement_Justification[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Ranking_Movement_Justification);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Ranking_Movement_Justification[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $Ranking_Movement_Justification[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
          <th class="eight" >


              <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="hq[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($hq);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $hq[$q] ?>"  selected > <?php echo $hq[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
           <th class="nine" >


            <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="account_status[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($account_status);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $account_status[$q]; ?>" selected > <?php echo $account_status[$q]; ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>


          </th>
          <th class="ten" >


            <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="account_industry[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($account_industry);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $account_industry[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $account_industry[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
          <th class="eleven" >


          <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="cg_sector[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($cg_sector);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $cg_sector[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $cg_sector[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>



          </th>

          <th class="twelfth" >


            <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Incumbent_SBU[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Incumbent_SBU);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Incumbent_SBU[$q]?>" selected > <?php echo $Incumbent_SBU[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>



          </th>
          <th class="thirteen" >


           <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="revenue_annual[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($revenue_annual);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $revenue_annual[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $revenue_annual[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
          <th class="fourteen" >


           <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="it_budget[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($it_budget);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $it_budget[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $it_budget[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>

          <th class="fifteen" >


          <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="alleviate_test_status[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($alleviate_test_status);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $alleviate_test_status[$q]?>" selected > <?php echo $alleviate_test_status[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
           <th class="sixteen" >


            <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="BDE[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($BDE);$q++){ 
        $c=0;



        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $BDE[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $BDE[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>


          </th>
          <th class="seventeen" >


           <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="BDE_Last_Meeting_with_Account[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($BDE_Last_Meeting_with_Account);$q++){ 
        $c=0;
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $BDE_Last_Meeting_with_Account[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $BDE_Last_Meeting_with_Account[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
          <th class="eighteen" >


          <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="BDE_Account_Interaction_Comments[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($BDE_Account_Interaction_Comments);$q++){ 
        $c=0;
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $BDE_Account_Interaction_Comments[$q] ?>"  selected > <?php echo $BDE_Account_Interaction_Comments[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
          <th class="nineteen" >


          <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Campaign_Ran[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Campaign_Ran);$q++){ 
        $c=0;
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Campaign_Ran[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $Campaign_Ran[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
          <th class="twenty" >


           <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Campaign_Date[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Campaign_Date);$q++){ 
        $c=0;
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Campaign_Date[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $Campaign_Date[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
           <th class="twentyOne" >


            <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Campaign_Outcome_Details[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Campaign_Outcome_Details);$q++){ 
        $c=0;
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Campaign_Outcome_Details[$q] ?>" selected > <?php echo $Campaign_Outcome_Details[$q] ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

          </th>
         <th class="twentyTwo" >


          <select class="multiselectLeaugeTable"  multiple="multiple" name="Last_Update[]">
                      <?php 

        for($q=0;$q<count($Last_Update);$q++){ 
        $c=0;
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Last_Update[$q] ?>"  selected > <?php if($Last_Update[$q]!="0000-00-00"){echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($Last_Update[$q]));}else{echo "NA";}

    //echo $Last_Update[$q]                 ?></option>
                        <?php 

        } ?>

                    </select>

        </th>
        </tr>
     <tr style="background:#bf6819;color:#FFF;font-size:12px;">
            <th class="one" >Account Name

            </th>
            <th class="two" >Account Parent Name

            </th>
            <th class="three" >Score

            </th>
           <th class="four" >Current Rank

          </th>
          <th class="five" >Previous Rank

          </th>
          <th class="six" >Trend 

          </th>
          <th class="seven" >Justification

          </th>
          <th class="eight" >HQ

          </th>
           <th class="nine" >Account Status

          </th>
          <th class="ten" >Industry

          </th>
          <th class="eleven" >Capgemini Sector

          </th>

          <th class="twelfth" >SBU

          </th>
          <th class="thirteen" >Latest Account Revenue

          </th>
          <th class="fourteen" >ITO Budget

          </th>

          <th class="fifteen" >Alleviate Status

          </th>
           <th class="sixteen" >BDE

          </th>
          <th class="seventeen" >BDE Last Meeting with Account

          </th>
          <th class="eighteen" >BDE-Account Interaction Comments

          </th>
          <th class="nineteen" >Campaign Ran

          </th>
          <th class="twenty" >Campaign Date 

          </th>
           <th class="twentyOne" >Campaign Outcome Details

          </th>
         <th class="twentyTwo" >Last Data Updated Date

        </th>
        </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

        <?php for($x=0;$x<count($selectTargetLeaugeTable);$x++){?>
            <tr style="font-size:12px;position:relative;z-index:-999999999;     word-wrap: break-word;" class="dataPart">
                <td class="one"><a href="fulldetails.php?comid=<?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['comid']; ?>"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Account Name']; ?></a></td>
                <td class="two"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Parent Name']; ?></td>
                <td class="three"><?php echo number_format($selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Score'],2); ?></td>
                <td class="four"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Latest Rank']; ?></td>
                <td class="five"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Previous Rank']; ?></td>
                <td class="six"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Ranking Trend voltility']; ?></td>
                <td class="seven"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Ranking Movement Justification']; ?></td>
                <td class="eight"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['hq']; ?></td>
                <td class="nine"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Account Status']; ?></td>
                <td class="ten"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Account Industry']; ?></td>
                <td class="eleven"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['CG Sector']; ?></td>
                <td class="twelfth"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Incumbent SBU']; ?></td>
                <td class="thirteen">Mn<?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Revenue Annual']; ?>&euro;</td>
                <td class="fourteen">Mn<?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['IT Budget']; ?>&euro;</td>
                <td class="fifteen"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Alleviate test status']; ?></td>
                <td class="seventeen"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['BDE']; ?></td>
                <td class="eighteen"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['BDE Last Meeting with Account']; ?></td>
                <td class="nineteen"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['BDE Account Interaction Comments']; ?></td>
                <td class="twenty"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Campaign']; ?></td>
                <td class="twentyOne"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Campaign Date']; ?></td>
                <td class="sixteen"><?php echo $selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Campaign Outcome Details']; ?></td>
                <td class="twentyTwo"><?php if($selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Last Update']!="0000-00-00"){echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($selectTargetLeaugeTable[$x]['Last Update']));}else{echo "NA";} ?></td>
           </tr>
        <?php }?>
            <tr style="font-size:12px;position:relative;    word-wrap: break-word;" >
                <td class="one"></td>
                <td class="two"></td>
                <td class="three"></td>
                <td class="four"></td>
                <td class="five"></td>
                <td class="six"></td>
                <td class="seven"></td>
                <td class="eight"></td>
                <td class="nine"></td>
                <td class="ten"></td>
                <td class="eleven"></td>
                <td class="twelfth"></td>
                <td class="thirteen"></td>
                <td class="fourteen"></td>
                <td class="fifteen"></td>
                <td class="seventeen"></td>
                <td class="eighteen"></td>
                <td class="nineteen"></td>
                <td class="twenty"></td>
                <td class="twentyOne"></td>
                <td class="sixteen"></td>
                <td class="twentyTwo"></td>
           </tr>
    </tbody>


    </table>
    <div class="topButton"><a style="color:#fff;" href="#top">TOP</a><s/div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
         <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>




    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("#showTopPush").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault(); 
            $("#navLeauge").slideToggle("slow");
                $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
        });     

        $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
            var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
            $(column).hide();
        });

        $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
            var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
            $(column).toggle();
        });
        $('.multiselectLeaugeTable').multiselect({


                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    maxHeight: 150,
                    selectAllValue: 'select-all-value',

                    onChange: function(option, checked) {
                            var papa = option.parent();
                            var buttonBeta = papa.next().children("button");
                    if(checked){
                        //alert("checked");

    $(".btn-group > button").removeClass("introWhite");
                            $(buttonBeta).addClass("introWhite");       
    $("td.one,td.two,td.three,td.four,td.five,td.six,td.seven,td.eight,td.nine,td.ten,td.eleven,td.twelfth,td.thirteen,td.fourteen,td.fifteen,td.sixteen,td.seventeen,td.eighteen,td.nineteen,td.twenty,td.twentyOne,td.twentyTwo").each(function(index,value){
                    if(option.val() == $(this).text()){
                //  alert($(this).text() +' ### '+option.val());
                        $(this).parent().show();
                        $("td select options").hide();
                    }else{
                        //$("td.one").hide();

                    }
                    });
                    }
                else{
    $(".btn-group > button").removeClass("introWhite");
                            $(buttonBeta).addClass("introWhite");
                                $("td.one,td.two,td.three,td.four,td.five,td.six,td.seven,td.eight,td.nine,td.ten,td.eleven,td.twelfth,td.thirteen,td.fourteen,td.fifteen,td.sixteen,td.seventeen,td.eighteen,td.nineteen,td.twenty,td.twentyOne,td.twentyTwo").each(function(index,value){         //alert($.contains( option.val(),$(this).parent));
                    if(option.val() == $(this).text()){

                        $(this).parent().hide();
                        $("td select options").show();
                        //alert("hh");
                    }else{

                    //  $("td.one").hide();
                    }



                    });
                    } 
                    },
                onSelectAll: function(checked) {
                 if(!checked){
                     //alert(checked);
                    $(".dataPart td").parent().hide();
                }else{
                    $(".dataPart td").parent().show();
                }
                }

                });


            var table = $('#newTable').DataTable({
            "scrollY": 400,
            "scrollX": true,
    colReorder: true,

     "bPaginate": false,
    "search":false, bFilter: false, bInfo: false,
        });






    });

    var start = new Date();
    $(window).load(function() { 
    //(new Date() - start);// makes sure the whole site is loaded
        var loadTime = new Date() - start;
        //jQuery("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        $("#preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @bub could you please let me which plugin or api provides this requirement.

Comment: You are going to have trouble finding answers by posting your entire code. Try breaking it down to chunks that you think might be casuing the problem and outlining important information about configurations and whatnot. Not many people are willing to pour over 100s of lines of code.